# Elements of Statistical Learning Integral Notation

Tags: machine-learning, probability, calculus

In equation 2.9 and 2.10 on page 18 of ESL we have

$$E(Y - f(X))^2 = \int [y - f(x)]^2 Pr(dx, dy)$$

However this notation confuses me. I'm rather expecting

$$E(Y - f(X))^2 = \int [y - f(x)]^2 Pr(x, y)dxdy$$

Is this just a matter of notation, or am I missing some more rigurous real analysis / probability theory explanation?

Comment: $\Pr(x, y)\,dx\,dy$ does not really work as a general statement as you often have $\Pr(x, y)=0$ as a probability.  In such cases you might want to use a density instead, but that cannot be generalised to discrete distributions.  $\Pr(dx, dy)$ is also an abuse of notation but might be understood in a handwaving way as roughly suggesting the probability of the point being in the set $[x,x+dx)\times[y,y+dy)$

Answer (score 0):

Using $\int ...\,\text dx\text dy$ generally implies that we're integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure, so in an integral like
$$
\int [y - f(x)]^2 P(x,y)\,\text dx\text dy
$$
this looks like we have a Lebesgue PDF $P(x,y)$ (while recognizing that this is an abuse of notation, albeit a common one) and are integrating $(y - f(x))^2 P(x,y)$ over $\mathbb R^2$ using the Lebesgue measure.

The notation
$$
\int [y - f(x)]^2 \,P(\text dx, \text dy)
$$
makes it explicit that we are integrating $(x, y) \mapsto [y - f(x)]^2$ over $\mathbb R^2$ using the measure $P$, so this is a Lebesgue integral, and there's no suggestion of densities or dominating measures. That makes this notation more acceptable. I think the intuition for this notation is that $\text dx$ and $\text dy$ are like small lengths so we can imagine plugging them into $P$ and measuring them, although it doesn't really mean that we're doing that and ultimately this is just a notation for a Lebesgue integral with the measure $P$.

An alternative notation that I think I see more often is
$$
\int [y-f(x)]^2 \,\text dP(x, y)
$$
where here even though $P$ is a measure and doesn't act directly on $x$ and $y$ (i.e. its domain is subsets of $\mathbb R$, not elements of $\mathbb R$), the $x$ and $y$ in the $\text dP$ are just to show that we're integrating over both of them.